# Why is my table appearing before my text?

Tags: floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I am trying to create a table after some text:

```
Some text. foobar foobar \\

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & a & c & & &  \\
\hline
$\{X, X', Y\}$ & & b &  & &  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, the table is appearing before the text even though I type if after I type the text. Why?

Comment: You are using a floating environment, `table`. Remove that and the `tabular` will appear where you place it.

Comment: See also the general reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/8057

Comment: I'd actually say this question is a duplicate of the one @user946850 pointed to?

Comment: @doncherry agreed, voting to close; David, this helps to keep the site tidy :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't need to use a caption, don't use `table` environment which is a floating object. Further, you have mentioned the option `[t]` which means the table will be at the top of the page. Use `[htb]` as the option as in this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{This is a table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & a & c & & &  \\
\hline
$\{X, X', Y\}$ & & b &  & &  \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details on the control of float placements refer to [this question and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).